# Exterior derivative of complex differential form

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, exterior-algebra

I have this question, from several complex variables:

Start with the differential form: $$\omega(z)=\sum_{\nu=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{\nu-1}\bar{z}_{\nu}}{|z|^{2n}} d\bar{z}[\nu] \wedge dz, $$

where $dz= dz_1 \wedge ... \wedge dz_n$ and $d\bar{z}[\nu] = dz_1 \wedge ...  dz_{\nu - 1} \wedge dz_{\nu +1} ... \wedge dz_n$.

Since $d(\bar{z}_{\nu} d\bar{z}[\nu]) = d\bar{z}_{\nu} \wedge d\bar{z}[\nu] = (-1)^{\nu -1} d\bar{z}$, we have

$$d\omega =\sum_{\nu=1}^{n} \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}_{\nu}} \bigg( \frac{\bar{z}_{\nu}}{|z|^{2n}} \bigg) d\bar{z} \wedge dz.$$

It's this line, right at the beginning, which I can't seem to compute. I'm pretty new to differential forms and exterior derivatives, so I can't see exactly how this is arrived at. I dont understand the first computation either ( $d(\bar{z}_{\nu} d\bar{z}[\nu]) = d\bar{z}_{\nu} \wedge d\bar{z}[\nu]$ etc. ).
Any help or hints would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall the product rule $d(\alpha \wedge \beta) = d\alpha \wedge \beta + (-1)^{|\alpha|} \alpha \wedge d\beta$. Hence, we have

$$ d(\bar{z}_{\nu} d\bar{z}[\nu]) = d(\bar{z}_{\nu}) \wedge d\bar{z}[\nu] + \bar{z}_{\nu} \wedge d(d\bar{z}[\nu]). $$

Applying the product rule again, you see that $d(d\bar{z}[\nu])$ is a sum of a wedge of forms, each containing $d^2 z_i$ and since $d^2 = 0$, it vanishes.

Hence,

$$  d(\bar{z}_{\nu} d\bar{z}[\nu]) = d(\bar{z}_{\nu}) \wedge d\bar{z}[\nu] = d\bar{z}_{\nu} \wedge d\bar{z}_1 \wedge \dots \wedge d\bar{z}_{\nu - 1} \wedge d\bar{z}_{\nu + 1} \wedge \dots d\bar{z}_n \\
= (-1)^{\nu - 1} d\bar{z}_1 \wedge \dots \wedge d\bar{z}_n = (-1)^{\nu - 1} d\bar{z} $$

where we used the anti-symmetry of the wedge product to move the factor $d\bar{z}_{\nu}$ into the correct place, by applying $\nu - 1$ adjacent swaps.

See if this is enough to get you going for the second calculation.

Comment: Yes, that's great, it all makes sense, and I used this to launch into the second calculation, which I managed to solve! Just a quick question though: The first sentence where you say recall the product rule $d(\alpha \beta) = d\alpha \wedge \beta + (-1)^{|\alpha|} \alpha \wedge d\beta$, my question is: Is $d(\alpha \beta)$ the same as $d(\alpha \wedge \beta)$ ? And so you have the same rule for $d(\alpha \wedge \beta)$ ? It doesn't help that I've seen differing notation in certain books for wedge product etc. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, it actually is. I shouldn't have used the notation $\alpha \beta$ at all.

Comment: Okay, cool. Yeh it's really the fault of the book I'm reading, they should write $d(\bar{z}_{\nu} \wedge d\bar{z}[\nu])$ rather than what they have. Thanks again.

Comment: Well, actually the exception for not using $\alpha \beta$ is when $\alpha$ is a 0-form (a function) and then it is common to write $f \cdot \beta$ (like in $\sin(x) \, dx$) and not $f \wedge \beta$. This is what your book does. One usually starts by defining differential forms and noting that they can be multiplied by functions. Then one extends the multiplication to general $k$ and $l$ forms such that if $k = 0$ (or $l = 0$) then it corresponds to the usual multiplication by functions. In this sense, $f \wedge \alpha = f \cdot \alpha$ and $\wedge$ extends $\cdot$.

Comment: Got it. For instance, in the well known rule $d(f\omega) = df \wedge \omega + f d\omega$ for function $f$ and form $\omega$ is written this way.